# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in User#register No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

I'm following Michael Hartl's book: ["RailsSpace building a social network with ruby on rails"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ca98/3b5098cd5957dc1842bb4bf3175406624bca.pdf?_ga=2.121598472.1814901715.1569094472-1963651489.1569094472). I'm on page 91,

When I try to go the registration page I get this:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in User#register No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}
```

Does anybody know why? Please help.

I have the `register.html.erb` file saved in `app/views/user` folder I don't know why I'm getting a url generation error.

Here is the code for `app/views/user/register.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Register</h2>
<% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
    <label for="screen_name">Screen name:</label>
    <%= form.text_field :screen_name %>
    <br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
    <br />
    <%= submit_tag "Register!", :class => "submit" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

> Here is the code for my user controller:

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout "site"

   def index
   end

   def register
   @title = "Register"
 end
end
```

> Here is my routes.rb file:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'user/index'
 get 'user/register'
 get  'site/index'
 get '/site/about'
 get 'site/help'

 root  'site#index'


 end
```

> Im trying to get to the registration page by typing:

`localhost:3000/user/register`

> why does it say:

`Showing C:/Users/Vanessa/rails_space/app/views/layouts/site.html.erb where line #16 raised`

> Here is what shows in my console:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"about", 
 :controller=>"user"}):
    13:      <div id="nav">
    14:
    15:       <%= link_to_unless_current "Home", :action => "index" %> |
    16:       <%= link_to_unless_current "About Us" , :action => "about" %> |
    17:       <%= link_to_unless_current "Help", :action => "help" %>
    18:
    19:         </div>
```

Thank everybody for all the help in advance.

> Here is my app/views/layouts/site.html.erb file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title><%= @title %></title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "site" %>
  </head>
 <body>

  <div id="whole_page">

 <div id="header">RailsSpace</div>
 <div id="nav">

  <%= link_to_unless_current "Home", :action => "index" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "About Us" , :action => "about" %> |
  <%= link_to_unless_current "Help", :action => "help" %>

    </div>
    <div id="content">
   <%= yield %>
      </div>
     </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Do you have a header partial or something similar that includes an "about" link? If so, show the header file, too. Also, it is *sometimes* helpful to show the whole stack trace to give the full context for the error.

Comment: @jvillian is correct. I would add, that if you do have an `about` action in user `users`controller then you will need to add an entry in your `routes.rb` file showing that an `about` url is handled by the `about` action in the `users` controller.

Comment: Hi Im a novice programmer, when you stack trace do you mean what shows in my console, or the full trace option from my browser window? Thanks to both of you guys, @jvillian

Comment: @jvillian I dont know what a header partial is

Comment: I mean what shows in your console. You show a snippet of it, but it's often useful to show more. Also, you should ditch that book you're using (as recommended in other comments in your other questions). It's old and causing you needless heartache.

Comment: In which file do you have `link_to_unless_current "Help", :action => "about"`?

Comment: I"ll ditch the book as soon as no one can solve a problem I post, so far every question I posted has been answered, that's why I never ditched it. Its my app/views/layouts/site.html.erb file @jvillian

Comment: Your problem is that you're using an archaic construct for `link_to_unless_current` instead of using a path helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the route incorrectly. There are several ways in which you can declare routes and it gets difficult to see the differences initially.

You have not specified which controller-action should get hit when user browses the path 'users/about'. For your syntax, Use:

`get 'users/about', to: 'user#about'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello there thanks @Nerve do I add this code to my routes.rb file?

Comment: Yes @JoshuaMatthews

Answer (score -2):

The helper method to go to that page may be incorrect.

Try running `rails routes` to see it.